# Include only partial entity in EF6 Include

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a model which includes Punches that can have Attachments that has properties for Id, Name as well as BinaryData.

If i do:

```
var result = context.PunchSet
   .Where(p => p.PunchType == punchType && p.Project.Id == projectId)
   .Include(c => c.Contractor)
   .Include(c => c.ClearedBy)
   .Include(c => c.CreatedBy)
   .Include(a => a.Attachments)
```

The query is slow as molassis since the attachments can be both many and large. In this case all I need is the Id and Name of the attachments. So I tried:

```
var result = context.PunchSet
    .Where(p => p.PunchType == punchType && p.Project.Id == projectId)
    .Include(c => c.Contractor)
    .Include(c => c.ClearedBy)
    .Include(c => c.CreatedBy)
    .Include(a => a.Attachments.Select(a2 => new Attachment() { Id=a2.Id, Name=a2.Name} );
```

But that ends up with this error:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties. Parameter name: path

Have not idea what that means and I've been stuck for hours. How can I include a partial entitiy in the result? I.e. don't read the binary data.

Comment: You can't partially include. However, if you just want to read, not update, you can leave out the attachments on the includes and load them separately.

Comment: How can I do that in the same query? I don't want to load 500 punches, then have to loop though them to fetch any attachments (if any). This would be a 5-minute job in good old SQL. Sometimes this EF6 stuff is getting to me.

Comment: If you need to load partially related entities, you will need to project your query  using an anonymous type or a DTO. As the exception explain, you can only refer navigation properties in the `Include` extension method

Answer (score 1):

You can try to select all desired properties in a single query and then join them together in memory.

```
db.PunchSet
    .Include(x => x.Contractor)
    // ... other includes of complete objects
    // then select properties for partial include
    .Select(x => new { obj = x, att = x.Attachments.Select(a => new { a.Id, a.Name }) })
    // end of database query context
    .AsEnumerable()
    // join the results in memory
    .Select(x =>
    {
        x.obj.Attachments = x.att.Select(a => new Attachment() { Id = a.Id, Name = a.Name }).ToList();
        return x.obj;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as shown below.

```
var result =  from p in context.PunchSet 
               where (p.PunchType == punchType && p.Project.Id == projectId) 
               select new { 
                           p,  
                           Contractor=p.Contractor,
                           ClearedBy =p.ClearedBy,
                           CreatedBy=p.CreatedBy,

                           Attachments= from a in p.Attachments
                                        select new {
                                                     Id=  a.Id,
                                                     Name =a.Name, 
                                                   },

             };

var result2 = result.AsEnumerable() 
                    .Select(c => c.p);
```

After that you can iterate as you wish  :)

```
foreach(var r in result2 ) 
{ 
    foreach(var a in r.Attachments) 
     {
       //your code; 
     }
}
```